# Random person encounter

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA 4, you could encounter random people, who would give you small side missions along side the main story line. You would encounter these people throughout the game.

You could spot these on the mini-map radar looking like a small man. These missions where are nice break to the main story line, and often had small hints to the main story.

**Are there any of these in GTA 5?**

**And if so, where can they be found?**
(in GTA 4 they where usually at fixed locations)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In GTA 5 there are two different kinds of "encounters". 
The first one are labeled "Strangers/Freaks" missions and they are depicted on the map with a **?** mark. They are in fixed position and every character has its own missions.

There are also [random events](http://www.gamersheroes.com/2013/09/19/grand-theft-auto-5-random-events-guide/) that triggers randomly while roaming around. These are label by a blue dot.

Comment: Actually, the **?** marks are more like side quests than really random encounters. The random encounters are depicted by blue dots, only appear if you're in the vicinity (just like in GTA 4, but unlike the **?** marks in GTA 5) and can be solved by any character (the **?** marks are character specific)

Comment: @Nolonar I assumed, according to his description, he was talking about the **?** missions. I improved the answer to include the random encounters too.

Answer (score 3):

The random encounters do exist. If you look at the [checklist](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/career/checklist) in Social Club, there is an area listing 52 possible Random Events. These events range from robberies, being a getaway driver, helping a mugged person, and the list goes on.

The random events are indicated on your mini-map typically by a dot which I believe is blue or red as you are in the vicinity of them. I have not yet seen an entire list of their locations. I don't believe these show on the map like the ?, which indicates a Strangers and Freaks mission.